# Prevent special characters in list item

Tags: list, out-of-the-box, special-characters

I am looking for an out-of-the-box solution (no code due to the lack of tools) for preventing the users from inputing list items with special characters. It would also be great if I could disallow names over a certain character length. Can somebody think of an easy solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you use InfoPath? You can use regular expressions with InfoPath. This [link](http://3sharp.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-in-sharepoint-lists/) may help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this simple method using **column validation**.

On List Settings > Column > Column Validation, add this:

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("!",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("~",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("#",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("$",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("%",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("*",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("(",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(")",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("+",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(";",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("[",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("]",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("\",
[ColumnName])),TRUE))
```

Source: [How to validate the special character on SharePoint List Column](http://fairulshahrizat.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/how-to-validate-special-character-on.html)

Comment: I am glad to read this

Answer (score 0):

For those who's wondering how to include also apostrophes `"` and `'` (or any other characters) in column validation just use `CHAR(34)` and `CHAR(39)` inside the FIND formula.

`...FIND(CHAR(34),[ColumnName])...`

Answer (score 0):

Please note there is a maximum of 20 items you can include in the above validation, which will NOT cover all the special characters.

But in windows certain ones cause problems for sure like `/\<>|*:;"'?`