# How to add two different formulas in column validation SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, column-validation, formula

Need to restrict the user from entering special characters and to make the input length equals to 24 i.e the user can enter only alphabets and numbers of length 24.

Comment: You can add length validation on 'Single Line of Text' and set it 24 via `Site Settings -> Site Columns -> Edit Site Column` or same goes for list via list settings, which can prevent user from entering long text. For column validation you need a custom logic to perform the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula that will prevent saving special characters in list:

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("!",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("~",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("#",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("$",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("%",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("*",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("(",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(")",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("+",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(";",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("[",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("]",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("\",
[ColumnName])),TRUE))
```

- Change the maximum number of characters for that column to "24".

[image]

- It will restrict users from entering more than 24 characters

[image]

Reference: [Prevent special characters in list item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219833/prevent-special-characters-in-list-item)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below formula to validate enter only numbers of length 24:

```
=IF(LEN([field])=24,ISNUMBER([field]+0),FALSE)
```

Comment: There could be "special characters" as well and not just numbers.